# Rotating simulator

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2017, simulator

I don't find any button or shortcut to rotate the UWP simulator on VS 2017.

I read through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441475.aspx), but none of the buttons (hand or mouse pointer icons) are shown for me.
What I see is simply a window in which my app is run, and it shows the number 000 000 in white on black background.

How can I rotate the simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the app in simulator and not in local machine. You will find the Clock wise and anti clock wise rotation icon on your simulator. using that you can rotate either left or right.

[image: Normal simulator] you can see the icons on the right side

[image: Icons to rotate] rotate icons

[image: Rotated simulator]

Comment: @tmighty if you are satisfied with the answer kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description you're running the app on **Local Machine** and not the **Simulator**.

Make sure that you *have checked* the **Simulator** in this dropdown menu
[image]
and then press F5 on your keyboard. You should then be able to see all those buttons.